# Is it a valid OData URI (and is there a bug in OData ABNF doc)?

Tags: odata

In a discussion with my colleague a question came up as to whether you have to add `eq true` after a call to `substringof` method in the OData URL filter:

```
http://localhost/Collection/WorkItems()?$filter=substringof('crash',Title)
http://localhost/Collection/WorkItems()?$filter=substringof('crash',Title) eq true
```

Now I'm consulting with the [ABNF for OData revised on 4/27/2012](http://www.odata.org/media/30002/OData%20ABNF.html). Looking at the `filter` expression form, it wants a `boolCommonExpr`:

```
filter                      =   "$filter" [ WSP ] "=" [ WSP] boolCommonExpr
```

A `boolCommonExpr` lists `boolMethodCallExpr` as one of its alternatives. But there is no definition for  the `boolMethodCallExpr` symbol in the ABNF!

So, I'm guessing it is a bug in the ABNF and the correct alternative listed there must be `boolMethodExpr`, not `boolMethodCallExpr`:

```
boolMethodExpr              =   endsWithMethodCallExpr /
                                startsWithMethodCallExpr /
                                substringOfMethodCallExpr /                                         
                                intersectsMethodCallExpr /
                                anyMethodCallExpr /
                                allMethodCallExpr
```

In this case a call to `substringof` method is allowed to go without `eq true` in the URI (as well as with `eq true`).

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to have " eq true" on the end of the URL. Any of the built-in functions that return Boolean should be good enough on their own. This looks like it was probably just a typo in the ABNF (especially given boolMethodCallExpr isn't defined). That particular document isn't even complete, and has several TODOs in it. A more definitive ABNF should be forthcoming as OASIS standardization of OData comes together.